# How do i set the value of a hidden field for ajax post datastring in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My form is:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="params" id="defaultform" value="{"action":"delete","data_id":"123456"}" />
</form>
```

my jQuery is:

```
$(document).on('click', '#deleteItem', function(e) {

    var dataString = $('#defaultform').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (response.totalrecords > 0) {
                alert(response.totalrecords);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

my function.php is:

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
$data_id = $_POST['data_id'];
//some php codes
$response = array('totalrecords' => $count);
echo json_encode($response);
```

but JavaScript code can not send POST variables, $_POST['action'] and    POST['data_id'];

How do I edit dataString value in jQuery code?
I want like this formed:

```
data : {"action":"delete","data_id":"12456"},
```

Comment: Quote mismatch here `value="{"...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your html code as follows

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="params" id="defaultform" value='{"action":"delete","data_id":"123456"}' />
<!--                                                    --^--------------------------------------^----     -->
</form>
```

And parse the JSON string data before sending

```
$(document).on('click', '#deleteItem', function(e) {

    var dataString = JSON.parse($('#defaultform').val());
    //             -----^-----

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (response.totalrecords > 0) {
                alert(response.totalrecords);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```